# display only value fields from the msg.payload in node red

Tags: javascript, node.js, snmp, net-snmp, node-red

I am working on node red (SNMP).

When I deploy, I have the output below:

> [ { "oid": "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.1.26", "type": 2, "value":
>   **104**, "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid": "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.2.27", "type": 2, "value": **104**,
>   "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid": "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.10.28",
>   "type": 2, "value": **1**, "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid":
>   "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.11.29", "type": 2, "value": 1, "tstr":
>   "Integer" }, { "oid": "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.12.30", "type": 2,
>   "value": **1**, "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid":
>   "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.13.31", "type": 2, "value": **1**,
>   "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid": "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.14.32",
>   "type": 2, "value": **101**, "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid":
>   "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.15.38", "type": 2, "value": **1**,
>   "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid": "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.100.39",
>   "type": 2, "value": **101**, "tstr": "Integer" }, { "oid":
>   "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.2.1.1.2.101.40", "type": 2, "value": **101**,
>   "tstr": "I ....

so I want to display all of the values from this output (104, 104, 1, 1 ....)

I am writing this function:

```
for(var i =0; i<Object.keys(msg.payload).length;i++)
{  
  msg.payload+=msg.payload[Object.keys(msg.payload)[i]].value;
}
return msg;
```

but I have an error:

> TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `for` loop is modifying `msg.payload` on each iteration - and because it is doing a `+=` it is turning it into a String. That means the second time through the loop, `msg.payload` is no longer the object it was at the start so the `Object.keys` call fails.

You should build up your result in a new variable and set `msg.payload` at the end:

```
var result = [];
var keys = Object.keys(msg.payload);
for(var i =0; i<keys.length;i++)
{  
  result.push(msg.payload[keys[i]].value);
}
// At this point, result is an array of the values you want
// You can either return it directly with:
//    msg.payload = result;

// or, if you want a string representation of the values as a
// comma-separated list:
//    msg.payload = result.join(", ");

return msg;
```