# Node-RED + DB2 - msg : string[18] "No response object"

Tags: node.js, rest, web-services, db2, node-red

So, I'm a beginner in Node-RED and need to make a simple API with DB2 queries through flows. I'm using [node-red-contrib-db2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-db2) to accomplish that. The thing is, I managed to get the results to several payloads to the debugger node, either triggered by timestamp or HTTP Request. However, I can't get these results on HTTP Reply and can't find the reason. Is it a problem with the db2 plugin or just me?

[image]

Exported nodes below:

```
[{"id":"96197abb.fd4098","type":"http in","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","url":"/wastes","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":150,"y":140,"wires":[["9affb306.caf7e"]]},{"id":"bda39d37.edb418","type":"http response","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","statusCode":"200","headers":{},"x":940,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"41708443.e4670c","type":"inject","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":220,"y":40,"wires":[["22a6e217.ead65e"]]},{"id":"9d1e6783.eb246","type":"ibmdb","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","mydb":"3a218407.1cca74","name":"IOCDATA","x":560,"y":40,"wires":[["80e51c1b.23b378"],[]]},{"id":"80e51c1b.23b378","type":"debug","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":730,"y":40,"wires":[]},{"id":"22a6e217.ead65e","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"SQL Query","func":"msg.database = \"iocdata\";\nmsg.payload = \"select * from viseu.waste_view\";\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":390,"y":40,"wires":[["9d1e6783.eb246"]]},{"id":"4a6bd014.f39868","type":"ibmdb","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","mydb":"3a218407.1cca74","name":"IOCDATA","x":500,"y":140,"wires":[["bda39d37.edb418","74e28d3e.039be4"],[]]},{"id":"9affb306.caf7e","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"SQL Query","func":"msg.database = \"iocdata\";\nmsg.payload = \"select * from viseu.waste_view where id = 1\";\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":330,"y":140,"wires":[["4a6bd014.f39868"]]},{"id":"74e28d3e.039be4","type":"debug","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":950,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"3a218407.1cca74","type":"IbmDBdatabase","z":"","host":"10.102.0.62","port":"50002","db":"iocdata"}]
```

Comment: please refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960435/display-only-value-fields-from-the-msg-payload-in-node-red

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with the ibmdb node you are using - it is not reusing the received message when it sends its results. That means the `msg.req` and `msg.res` properties provided by the HTTP In node are not set on the message by the time it reaches the HTTP Response node. This means the response node doesn't not what request to respond to.

To work around the issue, one approach, which isn't ideal, is to store msg.req and msg.res in flow context using a Change node before the `ibmdb` node, and then copy them back onto the msg after the ibmdb node. This isn't ideal because it can only handle one request at a time.

It would be best to raise an issue against the ibmdb node.

Comment: I can only get one record at a time with your workaround. Any more advice?

Comment: The node emits a message for each row in the result set rather than an array of results in a single message. This is not the best design for doing what you want. The best you can do is use the `join` node to try and reassemble the results into a single object.

Comment: How will I identify the last row?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reach success in my flow, at the cost of many workarounds and variable juggling. But it IS working now. Select count + select rows + join rows where msg.complete is set when count value is reached. Here is the code:

```
[{"id":"96197abb.fd4098","type":"http in","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","url":"/wastes","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":90,"y":140,"wires":[["d5f42a96.83f688"]]},{"id":"bda39d37.edb418","type":"http response","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","statusCode":"200","headers":{},"x":980,"y":260,"wires":[]},{"id":"4a6bd014.f39868","type":"ibmdb","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","mydb":"3a218407.1cca74","name":"SELECT waste_view","x":360,"y":200,"wires":[["35f99a5a.c7f87e"],[]]},{"id":"9affb306.caf7e","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"SQL Query","func":"msg.database = \"iocdata\";\nmsg.payload = \"select count(*) from viseu.waste_view\";\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":170,"y":200,"wires":[["4a6bd014.f39868"]]},{"id":"74e28d3e.039be4","type":"debug","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":890,"y":380,"wires":[]},{"id":"d5f42a96.83f688","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"req","pt":"flow","to":"req","tot":"msg"},{"t":"set","p":"res","pt":"flow","to":"res","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":260,"y":140,"wires":[["9affb306.caf7e"]]},{"id":"c3ebb136.aa8988","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"req","pt":"msg","to":"req","tot":"flow"},{"t":"set","p":"res","pt":"msg","to":"res","tot":"flow"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":800,"y":260,"wires":[["bda39d37.edb418"]]},{"id":"ca59ece2.844b3","type":"join","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","mode":"custom","build":"array","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","key":"topic","joiner":"\\n","joinerType":"str","accumulate":false,"timeout":"","count":"","reduceRight":false,"reduceExp":"","reduceInit":"","reduceInitType":"","reduceFixup":"","x":630,"y":260,"wires":[["c3ebb136.aa8988","74e28d3e.039be4"]]},{"id":"35f99a5a.c7f87e","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"SQL Query","func":"msg.rowcount = msg.payload[1];\nmsg.database = \"iocdata\";\nmsg.payload = \"select * from viseu.waste_view\";// fetch first \" + msg.count[1] + \" rows only\";\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":550,"y":200,"wires":[["327a8ae.a8ce2f6"]]},{"id":"2666e2ba.41dc8e","type":"ibmdb","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","mydb":"3a218407.1cca74","name":"SELECT waste_view","x":800,"y":200,"wires":[["9008e06f.bf6d7"],[]]},{"id":"ec61a7f3.68cf8","type":"debug","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"count","x":650,"y":320,"wires":[]},{"id":"327a8ae.a8ce2f6","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"rowcount","pt":"flow","to":"rowcount","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":670,"y":140,"wires":[["2666e2ba.41dc8e"]]},{"id":"90204f2d.8bafe8","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"rowcount","pt":"msg","to":"rowcount","tot":"flow"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":310,"y":320,"wires":[["6888cd0d.d00064"]]},{"id":"9008e06f.bf6d7","type":"counter","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","init":"0","step":"1","lower":"","upper":"","mode":"increment","outputs":"1","x":220,"y":260,"wires":[["90204f2d.8bafe8"]]},{"id":"6888cd0d.d00064","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"if rowcount === count","func":"if (msg.count === msg.rowcount) {\n    msg.complete = true;\n}\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":440,"y":260,"wires":[["ca59ece2.844b3","ec61a7f3.68cf8","a63f6ad6.26f08"]]},{"id":"a63f6ad6.26f08","type":"debug","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"rowcount","x":660,"y":380,"wires":[]},{"id":"3a218407.1cca74","type":"IbmDBdatabase","z":"","host":"10.102.0.62","port":"50002","db":"iocdata"}]
```

[image: flow screenshots]

**EDIT 21/02/2018:** the previous solution is not very good, because the counter saves its value mysteriously and I can't reset it as I wanted it. That makes the counter surpass the wished rowcount value. So, I had to make my own counter in a function node. New code below:

```
[{"id":"96197abb.fd4098","type":"http in","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","url":"/wastes","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":90,"y":60,"wires":[["d5f42a96.83f688"]]},{"id":"bda39d37.edb418","type":"http response","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","statusCode":"200","headers":{},"x":720,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"4a6bd014.f39868","type":"ibmdb","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","mydb":"3a218407.1cca74","name":"SELECT waste_view","x":740,"y":60,"wires":[["35f99a5a.c7f87e"],[]]},{"id":"9affb306.caf7e","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"SQL Query","func":"msg.database = \"iocdata\";\nmsg.payload = \"select count(*) from viseu.waste_view\";\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":530,"y":60,"wires":[["4a6bd014.f39868"]]},{"id":"74e28d3e.039be4","type":"debug","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":550,"y":280,"wires":[]},{"id":"d5f42a96.83f688","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"save req and res","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"req","pt":"flow","to":"req","tot":"msg"},{"t":"set","p":"res","pt":"flow","to":"res","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":290,"y":60,"wires":[["9affb306.caf7e"]]},{"id":"ca59ece2.844b3","type":"join","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"","mode":"custom","build":"array","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","key":"topic","joiner":"\\n","joinerType":"str","accumulate":false,"timeout":"","count":"msg.count","reduceRight":false,"reduceExp":"","reduceInit":"","reduceInitType":"","reduceFixup":"","x":390,"y":220,"wires":[["74e28d3e.039be4","c3ebb136.aa8988"]]},{"id":"35f99a5a.c7f87e","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"SQL Query","func":"msg.rowcount = msg.payload[1];\nmsg.database = \"iocdata\";\nmsg.payload = \"select * from viseu.waste_view\";\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":950,"y":60,"wires":[["327a8ae.a8ce2f6"]]},{"id":"2666e2ba.41dc8e","type":"ibmdb","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","mydb":"3a218407.1cca74","name":"SELECT waste_view","x":380,"y":140,"wires":[["90204f2d.8bafe8"],[]]},{"id":"327a8ae.a8ce2f6","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"save rowcount","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"rowcount","pt":"flow","to":"rowcount","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":160,"y":140,"wires":[["2666e2ba.41dc8e"]]},{"id":"90204f2d.8bafe8","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"get rowcount and count","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"rowcount","pt":"msg","to":"rowcount","tot":"flow"},{"t":"set","p":"count","pt":"msg","to":"count","tot":"flow"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":630,"y":140,"wires":[["6888cd0d.d00064"]]},{"id":"6888cd0d.d00064","type":"function","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"if count === rowcount","func":"//fix: msg.count ultrapassa msg.rowcount\nmsg.count = msg.count+1 || 1;\n\nif (msg.count === msg.rowcount) {\n    msg.complete = true;\n    msg.count = 0;\n}\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":880,"y":140,"wires":[["82ecfa98.9473d8"]]},{"id":"c3ebb136.aa8988","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"get req, res","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"req","pt":"msg","to":"req","tot":"flow"},{"t":"set","p":"res","pt":"msg","to":"res","tot":"flow"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":550,"y":220,"wires":[["bda39d37.edb418"]]},{"id":"82ecfa98.9473d8","type":"change","z":"b4aa8db5.217028","name":"save count","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"count","pt":"flow","to":"count","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":210,"y":220,"wires":[["ca59ece2.844b3"]]},{"id":"3a218407.1cca74","type":"IbmDBdatabase","z":"","host":"10.102.0.69","port":"50002","db":"iocdata"}]
```

[image]